# Print plugin phonegap

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Hi i'm quite confused on some parts of the Print Plugin or the Phonegap plugin. See i was able to implement the code even created my own plugin but i was no returning values from objective-c (xcode) back to javascript so it was safe to say that it was easy to understand.

On this code:

```
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/blob/master/iPhone/PrintPlugin/PrintPlugin.js
```

On this block of code:

```
PrintPlugin.prototype.callbackMap = {};
PrintPlugin.prototype.callbackIdx = 0;

PrintPlugin.prototype.print = function(printHTML, success, fail, options) {
if (typeof printHTML != 'string'){
    console.log("Print function requires an HTML string. Not an object");
    return;
}


//var printHTML = "";

var dialogLeftPos = 0;
var dialogTopPos = 0;


if (options){
    if (options.dialogOffset){
        if (options.dialogOffset.left){
            dialogLeftPos = options.dialogOffset.left;
            if (isNaN(dialogLeftPos)){
                dialogLeftPos = 0;
            }
        }
        if (options.dialogOffset.top){
            dialogTopPos = options.dialogOffset.top;
            if (isNaN(dialogTopPos)){
                dialogTopPos = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}

var key = 'print' + this.callbackIdx++;
window.plugins.printPlugin.callbackMap[key] = {
    success: function(result) {
        delete window.plugins.printPlugin.callbackMap[key];
        success(result);
    },
    fail: function(result) {
        delete window.plugins.printPlugin.callbackMap[key];
        fail(result);
    },
};

var callbackPrefix = 'window.plugins.printPlugin.callbackMap.' + key;
return PhoneGap.exec("PrintPlugin.print", printHTML, callbackPrefix + '.success',    callbackPrefix + '.fail', dialogLeftPos, dialogTopPos);
};
```

Especially this lines of code:

```
PrintPlugin.prototype.callbackMap = {};
PrintPlugin.prototype.callbackIdx = 0;
```

I'm confused by what that two lines of code does and why it is somehow important to incorporate or follow when you want to return values from xcode to javascript (**NOTE:** by me saying *why it is somehow important to incorporate or follow when you want to return values from xcode to javascript* i'm saying this based on what I've understood so far)

Can somebody explain how the two lines of code works and what are their purpose? Thank you.